# java trouble with SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I'm calling a web service from a jax-ws java client, when i recieve a response i get an exception saying that the content-type isn't supported,

the exception trace is as follows.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:360)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I have checked the headers in the soap request, it shows that the acceptable content-types are html/xml, text/jpg etc.. but not application/xml+soap.

when testing with SoapUI, things work perfectly.

we are using SOAP v1.1.. but (clearly) the client is using SOAP 1.2.. is there a way for us to parse the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using maven as a build tool, be sure to check your maven goal has XSoap1.2 as a protocol.. we had a similar issue we couldn't figure it out for weeks..

hope this helps you...

Answer (score 2):

Extrated from [someone else](http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com/2009/01/jax-ws-provider-api-based-endpoints-in_13.html)

```
  The @BindingType annotation is only necessary as we're using SOAP v1.2.  
  If you forget this line and you've specified SOAP v1.2 in your WSDL you'll 
  receive a runtime exception about the wrong content-type header as follows:

  SEVERE: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; 
  charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
  com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type:  
  application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

Maybe you are trying to use the wrong SOAP version.

Glassfish also has a [SOAP 1.2 page](http://metro.java.net/1.4/docs/soap12.html) to help.

Comment: we are using SOAP v1.1.. but (clearly) the client is using SOAP 1.2.. is there a way for us to parse the response?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove `binding="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"` from endpoint definition in the `sun-jaxws.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for re-opening such an old question.
I just want to add some more datail about WHY it should not be possible (at least in theory) to accept other MIMEs other than `text/xml` with a SOAP v1.1 server.

The [documentation about SOAP v1.1 on W3C (§6)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383526) states that

> HTTP applications MUST use the media type "text/xml" according to RFC 2376 when including SOAP entity bodies in HTTP messages.

While if we look at the most recent [documentation of SOAP v1.2 (§1.3)](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/#reltoxml) what we find is:

> The media type "application/soap+xml" SHOULD be used for XML 1.0 serializations of the SOAP message infoset

I think that a nice try could be to add an equivalent service implementing SOAP v1.2 and gradually switch to this new one. In the vast majority of cases the switch would "just work"